# Vue.js : Passing an external variable to a component through initialization?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass a variable (here, externalVar) to a component, directly when initializing. But I can't find how to do it (probably not understanding documentation well :/ ). What is the correct way to do it?

The initialization :

```
var externalVar = "hello world"

const leftmenu = new Vue({
    el: "#left-menu",
    template: "<CLM/>",
    components: {CLM},
    variableToPass: externalVar
});
```

The component I am initializing here is defined like this (getting back variableToPass in data):

```
<template src="./template-l-m.html"></template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
export default {
    name: 'leftmenu',
    components: {
        draggable
    },

    data () {
        return {
            jsonObject: this.variableToPass,
        }
    },
[ ... ]
</script>
```

But then , when I am trying to use this.jsonObject, it says that it's undefined. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) to pass data to child components

Dynamically bind a prop attribute on child component element using `:variable="variableToPass"`

```
var externalVar = "hello world"

const leftmenu = new Vue({
    el: "#left-menu",
    template: "<CLM :variable='variableToPass'/>",
    components: {CLM},
    data: {
        variableToPass: externalVar
    }
    
});
```

Define a props option in the child component

```
<template src="./template-l-m.html"></template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
export default {
    name: 'leftmenu',
    components: {
        draggable
    },
    props: ['variable'],
    data () {
        return {
            jsonObject: this.variable,
        }
    },
[ ... ]
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . :) I tried also to use props but I was missing the ":variable='variableToPass' " call in <template></template>

Answer (score 2):

Use [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data).

```
var externalVar = "hello world"

const leftmenu = new Vue({
    el: "#left-menu",
    template: "<CLM/>",
    components: {CLM},
    data: {
        variableToPass: externalVar
    }
});
```

That way you can access your variable like this `this.$data.variableToPass`

Answer (score 0):

Use [$options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)
in child component

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$parent.$options.variableToPass) // hello world
    this.jsonObject = this.$parent.$options.variableToPass
  }
```